# JupyterHub unreachable: Running on http://8000

Tags: python, jupyterhub

I am trying to get JupyterHub running on RHEL7.

I am getting a log output stating that the server is available on http://:8000 which seems a bit strange.  I have tried from another maching to connect to the "http://fully_qualified_host_name:8000" but this isn't working.

It all seemed so simple here:  https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Log output:

```
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:31.020 JupyterHub app:2120] Using Authenticator: jupyterhub.auth.PAMAuthenticator-1.0.0
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:31.020 JupyterHub app:2120] Using Spawner: jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner-1.0.0
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:31.023 JupyterHub app:1257] Loading cookie_secret from /opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:31.038 JupyterHub proxy:460] Generating new CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN
[W 2019-06-18 18:03:31.039 JupyterHub app:1532] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2019-06-18 18:03:31.039 JupyterHub app:1534] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:31.039 JupyterHub app:1563] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:31.067 JupyterHub app:2337] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[W 2019-06-18 18:03:31.068 JupyterHub proxy:642] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:31.068 JupyterHub proxy:645] Starting proxy @ http://:8000
18:03:31.596 [ConfigProxy] info: Proxying http://*:8000 to (no default)
18:03:31.598 [ConfigProxy] info: Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
18:03:32.178 [ConfigProxy] info: 200 GET /api/routes
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:32.178 JupyterHub proxy:319] Checking routes
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:32.178 JupyterHub proxy:399] Adding default route for Hub: / => http://127.0.0.1:8081
18:03:32.180 [ConfigProxy] info: Adding route / -> http://127.0.0.1:8081
18:03:32.180 [ConfigProxy] info: Route added / -> http://127.0.0.1:8081
18:03:32.182 [ConfigProxy] info: 201 POST /api/routes/
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:32.182 JupyterHub app:2422] JupyterHub is now running at http://:8000
^C[C 2019-06-18 18:03:36.370 JupyterHub app:2448] Received signal SIGINT, initiating shutdown...
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:36.371 JupyterHub app:2155] Cleaning up single-user servers...
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:36.371 JupyterHub proxy:705] Cleaning up proxy[19254]...
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:36.371 JupyterHub app:2187] ...done
(base) [knkb670@iecdalpptalpp01 bin]$ mysudo jupyterhub
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.038 JupyterHub app:2120] Using Authenticator: jupyterhub.auth.PAMAuthenticator-1.0.0
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.038 JupyterHub app:2120] Using Spawner: jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner-1.0.0
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.041 JupyterHub app:1257] Loading cookie_secret from /opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.056 JupyterHub proxy:460] Generating new CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN
[W 2019-06-18 18:03:41.057 JupyterHub app:1532] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2019-06-18 18:03:41.057 JupyterHub app:1534] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.057 JupyterHub app:1563] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.086 JupyterHub app:2337] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[W 2019-06-18 18:03:41.086 JupyterHub proxy:642] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.087 JupyterHub proxy:645] Starting proxy @ http://:8000
18:03:41.616 [ConfigProxy] info: Proxying http://*:8000 to (no default)
18:03:41.618 [ConfigProxy] info: Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
18:03:41.791 [ConfigProxy] info: 200 GET /api/routes
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.792 JupyterHub proxy:319] Checking routes
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.792 JupyterHub proxy:399] Adding default route for Hub: / => http://127.0.0.1:8081
18:03:41.793 [ConfigProxy] info: Adding route / -> http://127.0.0.1:8081
18:03:41.795 [ConfigProxy] info: Route added / -> http://127.0.0.1:8081
18:03:41.795 [ConfigProxy] info: 201 POST /api/routes/
[I 2019-06-18 18:03:41.795 JupyterHub app:2422] JupyterHub is now running at http://:8000
^C[C 2019-06-18 18:04:41.706 JupyterHub app:2448] Received signal SIGINT, initiating shutdown...
[I 2019-06-18 18:04:41.706 JupyterHub app:2155] Cleaning up single-user servers...
[I 2019-06-18 18:04:41.706 JupyterHub proxy:705] Cleaning up proxy[19283]...
[I 2019-06-18 18:04:41.707 JupyterHub app:2187] ...done
```

I am assuming I can connect to this remotely (the whole point of the Hub) from a different client.  The server is bash only.  Not sure where the config files are stored to do some digging, have tried to read the docs.

Not an expert in proxying.  I did consider just installing the Littlest JupyterHub, it may be simpler to get going - not sure if they can co-exist.